# how to make two dots moving along two curves?

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate, animation

I got this code from a previous thread and then modified it a bit.

```
s[t_] := -2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5;
Dynamic@Plot[{-2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5, 2 + 3 t}, {t, 0, 15}, 
  Mesh -> {{Clock[{0, 15}, 10, 10]}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
    Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

How can I change one dot to Blue and one Red? I tried Directive from MeshStyle but it doesn't work.
Would it be possible to add number `1` and `2` that move along the line with these points?

[image]

Comment: Can you try changing the `MeshStyle` by adding extra brackets? I mean `MeshStyle -> {{Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]}, {Directive[
    PointSize[Large], Blue]}}`? Does this work?

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 nope, both are red.

Comment: Hi, I extended you question and added an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263369/how-to-add-a-dynamic-mesh-point-to-each-line-in-a-given-plot). It goes beyond what you asked, so I wasn't sure you would find useful. But you might, and I hope you find it interesting in any event.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks, that looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use Overlay:

```
Dynamic[
  Overlay[
   {Plot[{-2.7 t^2+30 t+6.5},{t,0,15},Mesh->{{Clock[{0,15},10,10]}},
      MeshStyle->{Directive[PointSize[Large],Red]},
      GridLines->Automatic,PlotRange->{-150,100}],
    Plot[{2+3 t},{t,0,15},Mesh->{{Clock[{0,15},10,10]}},
      MeshStyle->{Directive[PointSize[Large],Green]},
      GridLines->Automatic,PlotRange->{-150,100}]}]]
```

Comment: this works fine but in my case the number of functions may be large so the code is a bit long.

Comment: Then maybe what you want to do is calculate all of the points, wrap them in Point with the appropriate decorations (like color, which you'll have to also calculate, maybe by using ColorData), and then use Epilog to overlay them. (Note, I haven't actually tried it yet.)

Comment: And it might be easier to use Animate than Dynamic. Again, I'd have to play around to compare the two approaches--it's just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

- 

```
Clear[colors, f, g];
colors = {Red, Blue};
f[t_] = -2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5;
g[t_] = 2 + 3 t;
Dynamic@(Block[{e = 0, τ = Clock[{0, 15}, 10, 10]}, 
   Plot[{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 15}, Mesh -> {{τ}}, 
     MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], GridLines -> Automatic] /. 
    Point[a_] :> {colors[[++e]], Point[a]}])
```

- `Epilog`

```
Clear[f, g];
f[t_] = -2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5;
g[t_] = 2 + 3 t;
Dynamic@Block[{τ = Clock[{0, 15}, 10, 10]}, 
  Plot[{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 15}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize -> Large, 
      Point[{τ, f[τ]}]}, {Pink, 
      Text[1, {τ, f[τ]}, {0, -2}]}, {Blue, 
      PointSize -> Large, Point[{τ, g[τ]}]}, {Cyan, 
      Text[2, {τ, g[τ]}, {0, -2}]}}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Construct two plots with desired mesh styles and combine with `Show`:

```
Dynamic @ Show[MapThread[ReplaceAll[p_Point :>
       {p, Text[Style[#4, 14], Offset[{5, 5}, p[[1]]], {-1, -1}]}] @ 
   Normal @ Plot[#, {t, 0, 15}, Mesh -> {{Clock[{0, 15}, 10, 3]}}, 
      MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize@Large, #2], PlotStyle -> #3, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] &, 
   {{-2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5, 2 + 3 t}, colors, ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {1, 2}}]]
```

[image]

**2.** You can post-process `Plot` output to inject colors before `Point`s:

```
colors = {Red, Blue};

Dynamic[ReplaceAll[Point[x_] :> Riffle[Point /@ x, colors, {1, -2, 2}]] @
  Plot[{-2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5, 2 + 3 t}, {t, 0, 15}, 
   Mesh -> {{Clock[{0, 15}, 10, 3]}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
   GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] ]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Comment: somehow it does not work in my PC (mathematica 12.2.0.0)

Comment: @hana, see if the first method works in your version/os.

Comment: yea, first one works fine.

Comment: would it be able add number `1` and `2` to the point and moving along these lines?  Normally the colors are enough but sometimes colors are similar so it's hard to know when it transits from this line to the other line (assume that two lines are connected). I assign each line with a number so if the that dot attached with a number then it's easy to see which line is that.

Comment: @hana, please see the update.

Comment: I got this error. 
https://ibb.co/dtGx29J

Comment: sorry, forgot to add `{1,2}` in the last argument of `MapThread`. Try the new version.

Comment: That is very nice. I'm sorry for this long. This is not asked in the question but I wonder how to do it as I think it's similar so may not need a new thread.  In the case above the point of the first one and second one are moving with the same `t` value from `0` to `15`. If I want to map each point of the first one to the second one as a function like `t2` of the second one relates with `t1` as this function `t2 = t1^2 -3`. So when `t1` runs from `0` to `15` if `t1 = 0` then `t2 = -3` so the moving points of first and second one are at different `t` location.

Comment: I just found that I can add more CLOCK for each.

Comment: if you have to use `Clock`, you can also do it with a single clock: `Dynamic@With[{c = Clock[{0, 15}, 10, 3]}, 
  Show[MapThread[
    ReplaceAll[
       p_Point :> {p, 
         Text[Style[#4, 14], Offset[{5, 5}, p[[1]]], {-1, -1}]}]@
      Normal@Plot[#, {t, 0, 15}, Mesh -> {{#5}}, 
        MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize@Large, #2], PlotStyle -> #3, 
        GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] &, {{-2.7 t^2 + 
       30 t + 6.5, 2 + 3 t}, colors,  ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {c, c^2 - 3}}]]]`

Comment: thanks for the help. I think it works well now!

Comment: `c = Clock[{-5, 5}, 10, 1] `works well if the range is continuous. 
What would you use if the range is something like `-5<t<1` and `t > 2`?
now `c` is now the union of `-5<t<1` and `2<t<5` and it is running on two ranges.