# How to add a dynamic mesh point to each line in a given plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

Building on this question, [how to make two dots moving along two curves?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263310/how-to-make-two-dots-moving-along-two-curves), let's say someone has given you the `Graphics[]` produced by `Plot[]` of one or more functions, and they've asked you to add animated points following along each curve.

So suppose we have `plot`, and did not know `plot` was generated by

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

***Q1***:
Is it possible to achieve the effect of the following dynamically changing mesh points by processing `plot`?:

```
Dynamic@Plot[{Sin[x], Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  Mesh -> {{Clock[{0, 10}]}}]
```

Please keep in mind that we don't know that the functions used to construct the plot were `Sin[x]` and `Tan[x]`. One drawback with the `Dynamic` code is that it regenerates the same plot just to change two mesh points, and that seems wasteful. If the functions are slow to compute, then the result would be unsatisfactory.

***Q2***:
Is it possible to add styling to the mesh points so that the point on each curve gets a different style, or have more than one point on each curve?
I'm not too particular about the syntax here, other than explicitly specifying at least one abscissa would be necessary, since that is what is shown in the `Dynamic` example above. And I'm not asking that arbitrary `MeshFunctions` be implemented, although it seems feasible.

Answer (score 6):

The function `addDynamicMesh[plot, meshopts...]` (see below) adds mesh points wrapped in `Dynamic`, so that they will change whenever appropriate. The `meshopts` include `Mesh :> spec` and `MeshStyle -> spec` and may be omitted.  The `Mesh :> spec` needs `RuleDelayed` to prevent `OptionValue` in the code from evaluating `spec`.  For instance, if `Mesh -> {{Clock[{0, 10}]}}`, the `Clock[]` will evaluate to `0` before being injected into `Dynamic` and we'll lose the dynamic animation.

Restriction: It is based on the current structure of the graphics returned by `Plot[]`, which hasn't changed in a while.  But it might change.  An alternative is given further below, but you lose some functionality.

#### Examples

The default `Mesh` behavior is a single point animated by `Clock[]` over the plotrange:

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic];
addDynamicMesh[plot, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
   Directive[PointSize[Medium], Blue]}]
```

This animates ten mesh points on each graph:

```
addDynamicMesh[plot, Mesh :> {{Mod[Clock[Infinity] + Range@10, 10]}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
   Directive[PointSize[Medium], Blue]}]
```

This adds a static mesh (though still wrapped in `Dynamic`) to `plot`:

```
addDynamicMesh[plot, Mesh -> {9}]
```

This shows mesh points at the current mouse $x$-coordinate, whenever the mouse is over the graphics:

```
meshx = Mean@First@PlotRange@plot;
addDynamicMesh[plot, 
 Mesh :> {{meshx = First@MousePosition["Graphics", {meshx, 0}]}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
   Directive[PointSize[Medium], Blue]}]
```

[image]

#### Code

For each function to be plotted, `Plot[]` puts the lines of its graph in `List` that starts with a styling `Directive[]`. It's convenient to get each list, because we also get the styling for the line.  Since we don't have the functions for each curve, we use `Interpolation` on their points.

```
getLineGroups // ClearAll;
getLineGroups[g_GraphicsComplex] := With[{coords = First@g},
   Cases[g,
    l_List /; 
      MemberQ[l, _Line] :> (l /. 
       Line[ics_, ___] :>   (* get rid of VertexColors *)
        Line[ics /. i : {__Integer} :> coords[[i]]]),
    Infinity]
   ];
getLineGroups[g_Graphics] := With[{glines = Join @@ 
      Cases[g, gc_GraphicsComplex :> getLineGroups@gc, Infinity]},
   Join[
    glines,
    Cases[
     DeleteCases[g, _GraphicsComplex, Infinity],
     l_List /; MemberQ[l, _Line] :>
      (l /. Line[p_, ___] :> Line[p]), (* get rid of VertexColors *)
     Infinity]
    ]
   ];
addDynamicMesh // ClearAll;
addDynamicMesh // Attributes = {HoldRest};
addDynamicMesh // Options = {
   Mesh -> Automatic, 
   MeshStyle -> Automatic};
addDynamicMesh[plot_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  With[{groups = getLineGroups[plot],
        pr = First@PlotRange[plot]},
   With[{
     mesh = OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, Mesh, Hold] /.
       { None -> {}
       , Automatic :> Mod[Clock@Infinity, pr[[2]] - pr[[1]], pr[[1]]]
       , Hold[n_Integer] | Hold[{n_Integer}] :> 
          Hold@Evaluate[Subdivide[pr[[2]], pr[[1]], n + 1][[2 ;; -2]]]
        },
     meshFN = Evaluate[
          MapThread[
           Function[{style, line},
            line /. Line[p_] :> 
              With[{y = Interpolation[p, 
                  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
                    "WarningMessage" -> False}]},
               Hold@
                If[NumberQ[y[#]], (* delete Indeterminate y *)
                 {style, Point[{#, y[#]}]},
                 {}]
               ]
            ],
           {Charting`getPlotStyles[None][ (* convenient internal func *)
             Length@groups,               (* not hard to code tho' *)
             OptionValue[MeshStyle]],
            groups}
           ]
          ] & // ReleaseHold},
     mesh /. Hold[m_] :> (* mesh needs to be held *)
       Show[             (* until injected in Dynamic *)
        plot,
        Graphics[{Dynamic[meshFN /@ Flatten@{m}]}]
        ]
     ]];
```

#### Alternative

For `Graphics[]` not produced by `Plot[]` -- or if the workings of `Plot` change -- then we could just get all lines, instead of groups of lines.  The groups were convenient for styling each group in a similar way, so hopefully they won't go away.  But if they do:

```
getLineCoords // ClearAll;
getLineCoords[g_GraphicsComplex] := With[{
    coords = First@g},
   Cases[
    Cases[g, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity] /. 
     i : {__Integer} /; Length[i] > 2 :> coords[[i]],
    m_ /; MatrixQ[m, Developer`RealQ],
    Infinity]
   ];
getLineCoords[g_Graphics] := With[{
    glines = 
     Join @@ Cases[g, gc_GraphicsComplex :> getLines@gc, Infinity]},
   Join[
    glines,
    Cases[
     Cases[
      DeleteCases[g, _GraphicsComplex, Infinity],
      Line[p_] :> p, Infinity],
     m_ /; MatrixQ[m, Developer`RealQ],
     Infinity]
    ]
   ];
getLines // ClearAll;
getLines[g_] := Line /@ getLineCoords[g];
```

Example: Notice in the output of the following that both the `Sin[x]` and `Tan[x]` curves are broken up at the exclusions coming from `Tan[x]`.  This means there are eight curves to style, in order s1, s2, s3, s4, t1, t2, t3, t4, and the two styles alternate through this list, so that styling of the point on the sine curve alternates between the two styles, as it does also for the tangent graph. To fix it, determine the order of the curves and construct an appropriate `MeshStyle`. No easy way to do this without experimental inspection occurs to me without assuming the underlying structure of the `Graphics[]`.

```
Block[{getLineGroups = getLines},
 addDynamicMesh[plot, Mesh :> Clock[{0, 10}], 
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
    Directive[PointSize[Medium], Blue]}]
 ]
```